# how to force Razor not to generate extra html attributes

Tags: html, razor, razor-2

**Update 1:**

As someone mentioned below to turn off the jQuery unobtrusive validation, I have moved those js files onto a cshtml page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

But the issue remains.

---

I'm using Razor (Version 2 I guess) + Twitter Bootstrap

I have a date-time picker on my page and it requires a textbox input.

As pure html cannot bind the user inputted value to the related property, so I have to use Razor Html helper.
Below is the 2 ways to have a textbox input on the page.

```
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.event_date_time, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter date and time" })
```

But it seems that the Razor helper generates extra html attributes for its own validation purpose and those attributes disturb the Boottrap to correctly display the date-time picker.

Please have a look about the html code generated by the Razor Html helper.

```
<input class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field event_date_time must be a date." data-val-required="The event_date_time field is required." id="event_date_time" name="event_date_time" placeholder="Enter date and time" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM">
```

Now my question is : how to force Razor Helper not to generate the extra html attributes?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you have unobstrusive validation enabled. Are you trying to disable the validation altogether or just for this particular situation?

Comment: Of course pure html can bind. Just set the id of the text box to 'event_date_time'. You always have the option of using pure html instead of razor

Comment: @BabakNaffas Hi Babak, please see my update 1. thx

Comment: @malik Hi Malik, does the ID od the text box has to be the exactly same as the property name in the Model?

Comment: @Franva Yes. Whatever you see in your view source/firebug/etc, is what  the razor helper created. So you can copy that html, and remove the stuff you dont want in there, and use that in your cshtml file. But with some stuff like validation, those extra `data-*` stuff is required for them to work.

Comment: @malik thanks Malik :) that's a good way to get around. :) will put on my table.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around and weird solution.

Just keep both my html control and Razor helper, then set the html control : display: none;
then the Razor generated textbox will work with the date-time picker.
I know it's weird and I have no idea why it works.

So here is the code:

```
 <input type='text' class="form-control" style="display:none;"/>

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.event_date_time, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter date and time" })
```

I will leave the answer here for a couple of days to see whether someone can figure out why it works in this way and what's the proper way to do it.

Many thanks.